# Sending list and dict as parameters to a REST service using Requests

Tags: python, web-services, rest

I have a (dummy) web service which receives parameters as a list and a dict as parameters:

```
class Dummy:
exposed = True

def POST(self, l, d):
    return str(l) + '----' + str(d)
```

I use [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to send a post request:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
d = ['1':1, '2':2, '3':3]
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/Dummy/', {'l':l, 'd':d})
print r.text
```

The result that I receive is `u"[u'1', u'2', u'3']----[u'1', u'3', u'2']"` which means only the keys of the dict are sent. My current solution is to send a string representing a dict and convert it back to dict on server side.

I wonder if there is a way to send both list and dict to a web service via POST.

Comment: You should probably use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The docs from requests have a [simple example](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

The dict will be sent as a form.